# Axios callback not logging value

Tags: api, asynchronous, axios, callback, spotify

I'm making a post request to the Spotify API, and it seems to work fine, but nothing is being returned from the callback. Any ideas?

```js
const spotifyReq = async () => { 
    try {
        await axios.post(
            "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token", "grant_type=client_credentials", {
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'Basic' + (Buffer.from(client + ':' + secret, 'base64')),
                    
                    'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                },
                auth: {
                    username: "client",
                    password: "secret"
                }
            }, (res) => {
            console.log(res)
        })
    } catch (err) {
        if (err.request) {
            console.log(err.response.data)
        } else if (err.response) {
            console.log(err.response.data)
        } else {
            console.log(err)
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Open the developer tools of your browser and check the network tab. There you can see what requests have been sent, what happened to them and what was returned.

Comment: What if I am trying to use it from terminal only?

Comment: I honestly don't know. Maybe it's a good idea to run that part of the program in a browser for testing the behaviour.

Comment: That shouldn't be too hard - just create a blank html file, add your script and open that file in a browser. Then you can use the cool developer tools that all modern browsers have to read error messages and to see network traffic.